# Is there a way to get the most dominant color of an image in Javafx

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

i am trying to build an app, and i need the background of my vbox to be thesame as the most dominant color of the image attached to it, now am working with random image, so i need my program to be able to calculate this by itself.
Please any suggestions

Comment: [`Image#getPixelReader()`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/image/Image.html#getPixelReader()).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but there is no *nice* way to do it.

This code isn't perfect (I'm on my phone), but consider the following code:

```
// Read the image.

final InputStream is = new FileInputStream("Path\\To\\Image");
final Image img = new Image(is);

// Read through the pixels and count the number of occurrences of each color.

final PixelReader pr = img.getPixelReader();
final Map<Color, Long> colCount = new HashMap<>();

for(int x = 0; x < img.getWidth(); x++) {
  for(int y = 0; y < img.getHeight(); y++) {
    final Color col = pr.getColor(x, y);
    if(colCount.containsKey(col)) {
      colCount.put(col, colCount.get(col) + 1);
    } else {
      colCount.put(col, 1L);
    }
  }
}

// Get the color with the highest number of occurrences .

final Color dominantCol = colCount.entrySet().stream().max(Map.Entry.comparingByValue()).get().getKey();
```

**EDIT 1:**

You may want to implement some form of threshold method. For example, you could categorize each color as either red, green, or blue (real-world application you would want many more ranges of shades). Then, use the average or median from the range with the most matches.

Comment: Sorting the map just to get the key for the max value is overkill

Comment: Thanks for the reminder @Clashsoft. I edited my answer.

Comment: thanks, it works,i can now set the background color from the dominant color in image

Comment: sorry, one more question is there a way to transfer this color to a css format cause when i tried converting the derived color to string and then setting it in my css, it doesnt work

Comment: @TuleSimon `String.format("#%02x%02x%02x", col.getRed() * 255, col.getGreen() * 255, col.getBlue() * 255)`.